# Linked List looping output in C

Tags: c, loops, linked-list

So I am fairly new to C and have to make a database with linked lists, I have tried it and can't find the problem. When one node is added it prints it out fine, but when more are added it just loops when printing out the recently added nodes and never prints out the last node (the one first entered).

```
struct person
 {
  char sex;
  int age;
  struct person *prev, *next;
 };
struct person* first = NULL;



static void add_person(void)
{

 struct person* temp = (struct person*)malloc(sizeof(struct person));
   if (temp == NULL)
       printf("Unable to allocate memory");
 {
 printf("Enter the gender: ");
 scanf("%c", person->sex);

 printf("Enter the age: ");
 scanf("%d", person->age);

 if(first==NULL){
    temp->prev=NULL;
    temp->next=NULL;
    first=temp;
 }
 else{
    temp->prev=NULL;
    temp->next=first;
    first->prev=temp;
    first=temp;
 }
 free(temp);
}


static void print(void)
{
  struct person* present = first;
  while(present != NULL){
    printf("%c", present->sex);
    printf("%i", present->age);
    present=present->next;
  }
```

Comment: Where the `start` variable is declared?

Comment: Perhaps `start` should be `first`? Why are you freeing `temp` before returning?

Comment: yea sorry start is first, il change it now. Should I not be freeing temp in that place?

Comment: Why on earth would you want to free it? This is where your linked list is stored.

Comment: oh ok, i just got rid of it and it works, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You should put `temp` instead of `person`

```
 printf("Enter the gender: ");
 scanf(" %c", &temp->sex);

 printf("Enter the age: ");
 scanf("%d", &temp->age);
```